# Where is the documentation on changing R's order of evaluation?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am new to R and am learning about the `dplyr` package. In the documentation for `%>%` I can read about how the packages changes the grammar or the language. For example,

> The magrittr pipe operators use non-standard evaluation.

I would like to learn more about how this is done, but am unsure of what keywords to use. Can someone point me to a documentation page on what features R exposes that allows one to write code that modifies the order of evaluation?

Comment: Questions just asking for links to other resources are frowned upon. It's better to ask a question which can clearly be answered. The source code for `magrittr` is available on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the R console enter:

```
?Syntax
```

Also see the [infix and prefix](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Infix-and-prefix-operators) section of the R Language Definition manual.